# Loop through the given dates

Tags: php, loops, date

I have a weird scenario like I have given four dates and I need to call a method based on these dates. That is first I need to call the function for start time as 1st of the month and end time as 15th of the month. This function again needs to be called for start time 16th of the month and end date 30th/31st of the month. I can call the functions two times with hard-coded values, but is there any better method to do this?

I am using Carbon library for PHP and creating the dates like this

```
$this->firstDay = Carbon::now()->startOfMonth()->subMonth()>toDateString();

$this->lastDay = Carbon::now()->subMonth()->endOfMonth()>toDateString();

$this->firstHalf   = Carbon::parse($this->firstDay)->addDays(15)->toDateString();

$this->secondStart = Carbon::parse($this->firstDay)->addDays(16)->toDateString();
```

and the method I need to call have the following code

```
return $this
            ->database
            ->table('table')
            ->selectRaw('SUM(points) AS points, id')
            ->whereBetween('date', [$firstDay, $firstHalf])
            ->groupBy('id')
            ->get();
```

These will give the corresponding dates and now I need to run the method as start time as `firstDay` and end time as `firstHalf` and then again to call with start time as `secondStart` and end as `lastDay`. Basically what I am trying to do is to avoid the duplication of the code by writing the query two times.

How can this be done?

Comment: Run what method? Not clear what *"this"* is in *"How can this be done?"* or what the specific problem is

Comment: The method if to execute a query in which these dates will come as the values for where between.

Comment: And what is the problem there? Suggest you update question with a more specific set of details. Nothing suggests any query in current question , just a vague mention of a *"method"*

Comment: updated. What I am trying to do is to call the method in some loop or something, so I don't need to write the query two times with these two date ranges

Comment: just wrap it in a function that passes in the 2 dates and returns those results, then call function twice

Comment: Updated my answer but seeing these comments now, I'm even more confused. Sounds like charlietfl's comment above should do it

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off setting the variables to the actual `Carbon` instances.

Taking into consideration months that have 28 or 29 days, you can grab the last day of the previous month and divide that by 2 to find the mid-point.

```
$lastMonth = Carbon::now()->subMonth();

$start = $lastMonth->startOfMonth();
$end = $lastMonth->endOfMonth();
$middle = floor($end->days / 2);

$firstDay = $start->toDateString();
$firstHalf = $start->addDays($middle)->toDateString();

$lastDay = $end->toDateString();
$secondHalf = $start->addDays($middle + 1)->toDateString();
```

*Edit: updated example to reflect the variables used in your updated question*

*Edit 2:*
If you're using Laravel/Eloquent, you may even be able to pass the actual `Carbon` instances directly to the Query Builder, without calling `toDateString()`.